# How do I limit the number of ROWS being returned in my SQL Server Function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, limit

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_CUSTOMER_DATA]  
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @customerID bigint,
    @maxRows int,
    @offset int,
    @rows int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    SELECT *
        FROM SS_CustomerCard AS SS_CC 
        INNER JOIN SS_PersonalRepresentative AS SS_PR
        ON SS_PR.customerID = SS_CC.ID
        INNER JOIN SS_ApplicationStatus AS SS_AS
        ON SS_AS.CustomerID = SS_CC.ID
        WHERE
            SS_CC.ID='@customerID'
        ORDER BY SS_AS.EventDateTime DESC, SS_CC.FirstName DESC, SS_CC.LastName DESC
        OFFSET @offset ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @rows ROWS ONLY
)
GO
```

I want to pass a parameter to limit the number of rows being returned (maxRows)

Comment: Can you just do [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)?

Comment: What's the difference between `@rows` and `@maxRows`?

Comment: rows is being used to fetch the number of rows. I wanted maxrows to limit the number of total rows being returned. (I need to use the two inner joins)

Comment: @LionelFoxcroft i am having trouble using TOP with OFFSET

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TOP()` clause in the `SELECT` statement.

Here is a conceptual example.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, vehicleMake VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @tbl (vehicleMake) VALUES
('Chevrolet'),
('Tesla'),
('Audi'),
('Nissan');

DECLARE @tableVariable TABLE (ID INT, vehicleMake VARCHAR(20));

DECLARE @topRows INT = 2;

INSERT INTO @tableVariable
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY id;

SELECT TOP(@topRows) *
FROM @tableVariable
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: I am having trouble using TOP when I use OFFSET. Can you provide an example with using both?

Comment: @softwareisfun, I modified the answer. Put your current `SELECT` inside the CTE (or derived table). This way the `TOP()` clause won't conflict with `OFFSET`.

Comment: @softwareisfun, it looks like both CTE and derived table need their own `ORDER BY` clause. It creates a problem.

Comment: You could try to populate a temp table and `SELECT TOP() ...` out of  it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to limit the total number of rows BEFORE the `OFFSET/FETCH`. If so, you need to put it in a subquery/derived table, and add another `ORDER BY`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_CUSTOMER_DATA]  
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @customerID bigint,
    @maxRows int,
    @offset int,
    @rows int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (@maxRows) all_needed_columns_here_aliased_if_necessary
        FROM SS_CustomerCard AS SS_CC 
        INNER JOIN SS_PersonalRepresentative AS SS_PR
          ON SS_PR.customerID = SS_CC.ID
        INNER JOIN SS_ApplicationStatus AS SS_AS
          ON SS_AS.CustomerID = SS_CC.ID
        WHERE
            SS_CC.ID=@customerID
        ORDER BY SS_AS.EventDateTime DESC, SS_CC.FirstName DESC, SS_CC.LastName DESC
    ) t
    ORDER BY EventDateTime DESC, FirstName DESC, LastName DESC
    OFFSET @offset ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @rows ROWS ONLY
)
GO
```

Comment: I am getting this error 
The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 't'.

Comment: Yeah you would have had that issue anyway, you need to specify the exact column names in the inner query